# Binding errors While Binding null values to Width and Height of the wpf control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, double

Our project needs that we bind many properties of the control such as `Height`, `Width`, `MinHeight`, `Row`, `Column`, `rowspan`... etc. While doing so we observed binding errors to when these values are `null` which we will be getting from DB.

To illustrate, my **MainWindow.xaml.cs** looks like this.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //TextWidth  id null
        TextBlockSize1 = new ItemSize() { TextHeight=20 };
        //TextWidth is null
        TextBlockSize2 = new ItemSize() { TextWidth = 40 };
        //TextHeight is null and TextWidth is null
        TextBlockSize3 = new ItemSize() { TextWidth = 40 };
        textblock1.DataContext = TextBlockSize1;
        textblock2.DataContext = TextBlockSize2;
        textblock3.DataContext = TextBlockSize3;
    }
    public ItemSize TextBlockSize1 { get; set; }

    public ItemSize TextBlockSize2 { get; set; }

    public ItemSize TextBlockSize3 { get; set; }
}

public class ItemSize
{
    public double? TextHeight { get; set; }
    public double? TextWidth { get; set; }
}
```

and **MainWindow.xaml** looks like this.

```
<Window x:Class="WPfAppln1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:WPfAppln1.Controls"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel >
         <TextBlock Name="textblock1" Text=" TextBlock 1"  Width="{Binding TextWidth}"  Height="{Binding TextHeight}"></TextBlock>
         <TextBlock Name="textblock2" Text=" TextBlock 2"  Width="{Binding TextWidth}"  Height="{Binding TextHeight}"></TextBlock>
         <TextBlock Name="textblock3" Text=" TextBlock 3"  Width="{Binding TextWidth, TargetNullValue=Auto}"  Height="{Binding TextHeight, TargetNullValue=Auto}"></TextBlock>     
   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Following binding errors are shown for this in the output widow:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : 'WPfAppln1.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='<null>' BindingExpression:Path=TextWidth; DataItem='ItemSize' (HashCode=43929715); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='textblock1'); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='<null>' BindingExpression:Path=TextHeight; DataItem='ItemSize' (HashCode=57104612); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='textblock2'); target property is 'Height' (type 'Double')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='<null>' BindingExpression:Path=TextHeight; DataItem='ItemSize' (HashCode=59587750); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='textblock3'); target property is 'Height' (type 'Double')
    The thread '<No Name>' (0x2c60) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

And due of these errors, application is taking long time to load the screens.

So the question are how to accommodate nullable values in binding to the wpf controls and how to provide a default value such as 'auto' for width properties of the control when the bound value is null.

Comment: Are you sure that these binding errors slow down your application? I am just curios, because I always thought that binding errors in the output window do not affect performance ....

Comment: @SvenG : Yes, these binding errors may cause performance issues, I have personally faced this with DataGrid's. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/02/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-2-performance-tuning.aspx) is a MS link saying - **"WPF tries several different ways to resolve path errors, including searching for attached properties and this is quite expensive"**, also see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/wpf/thread/eb6b83b5-bcbb-4e1f-af03-cde68cfe827d)

Comment: Thanks for the insight that's very useful information for me!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`TargetNullValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx)(in case source is null) or [`FallbackValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx)(in case binding fails e.g. `DataContext` is `null`)

**Update:**

Thanks Dean for pointing that out, I wrongly assumed that `Auto` will work (i.e. `TypeConverter` will take care of conversion).

But, you can still use auto property and provide `Auto` value in XAML using [`x:Static` Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) like this -

```
<TextBlock Name="textblock1" Text=" TextBlock 1"  
    Height="{Binding TextHeight, TargetNullValue={x:Static System:Double.NaN}, 
               FallbackValue={x:Static System:Double.NaN}}">
</TextBlock>
```

`Value="{x:Static System:Double.NaN}"` can also be used in `DataTrigger` approach like this -

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style>
       <Setter Property="Control.Width" Value="{Binding Path=TextWidth}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
               Binding="{Binding Path=TextWidth}"
               Value="{x:Null}">
               <Setter Property="Control.Width" Value="{x:Static System:Double.NaN}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Note: will require this namespace -

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

**Old Code:**

```
<TextBlock Name="textblock1" Text=" TextBlock 1"  Width="{Binding TextWidth}"  
    Height="{Binding TextHeight, TargetNullValue=Auto, FallbackValue=Auto }">
</TextBlock>
```

Another solution can be to have a trigger like this -

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding Path=TextWidth}"
                Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Control.Width" Value="Auto" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding Path=TextHeight}"
                Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="Auto" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Comment: -1 : you cannot use the string 'Auto' as a TargetNullValue or FallbackValue so your solution wont work

Comment: +1 Thanks for TargetNullValue. I just wanted to reuse a nullable bool in a bool target so this worked `IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ItemEnabled, Converter={StaticResource negate}, TargetNullValue=false}"`

Comment: @reasra glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution (in my opinion) is not to use auto properties.

e.g.

```
private double textHeight = Double.NaN;
public double TextHeight
{
    get { return textHeight; }
    set { textHeight = value; }
}

private double textWidth = Double.NaN;
public double TextWidth
{
    get { return textWidth; }
    set { textWidth = value; }
}
```

Comment: I using dependency properties but this worked out for me.  Here's what I got:  public double? Height
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(HeightProperty);
            set
            {
                if (value == null)
                    Height = double.NaN;
                else
                    SetValue(HeightProperty, value);
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

If your two `double?` properties do not absolutely need to be nullable, you can just make them regular `double` properties. This would default to 0.

If that's not possible, or 0 is an unacceptable default, I would favour the FallbackValue solution myself. If your default value must be 'Auto' though (as mentioned above), you cannot set 'Auto' as a `FallbackValue`.

> The default value of Height and Width is not 0; it is Double.NaN.
>   Height and Width support the ability to be an unset "Auto" value.
>   Because Height and Width are double values, Double.NaN is used as a
>   special value to represent this "Auto" behavior.
>   (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width(v=VS.95).aspx)

If you can't set `Double.NaN` to a `FallbackValue` (I've not tried), I would use a Converter myself. If the target value is `null`, return `Double.NaN` instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx for more on IVAlueConverter.